# NetBeans Glassfish 4 web application does not run

Tags: java, web-applications, netbeans, glassfish

I have created new web application project, and pressed **Run** button. There appears loading bar in the bottom-left corner of NetBeans.

I have been waiting for 20 minutes and project does not run.

Then this error appears:

```
Project is not deployed
```

Comment: Please, Show the server log.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to check on **Deploy Browser on Run**.

You can do this through following steps:

1. Your project ***Right Click***
2. Choose ***Properties***
3. Go to ***Run***
4. Then check on ***Deploy Browser on Run***

***Snapshot***

[image]